# Rewriting a function assuming variables are real

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been tasked with finding all the possible values of $a$ and $b$ such that $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ for which a function $f(x) = e^{bx}$ is a solution to the linear differential equation of $f''(x) + af'(x) - f(x) = 0$.

I computed the first and second derivatives of $f(x)$ and substituted back to get:

$b^2e^{bx} + abe^{bx} - e^{bx} = 0$. I simplified this to:

$e^{bx}(b^2 + ab - 1) = 0$.

I inputted this into wolfram and it said that if $a, b, x$ are assumed to be real then we can rewrite that as $b(a + b) = 1$. Is this correct and if so, how did we get here? Is the final answer $b = 0, a = -1, a = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct since $e^{b x} > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ so if $e^{b x} (b^2 + a b - 1) = 0,$ then necessarily $b^2 + a b - 1 = 0$ or $b(a + b) = 1.$ If you want to solve this over the reals (note $a$ is already given), then you get the solutions $$b_{1, 2} = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}.$$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Perfect, so it makes sense that the correct answer is $b=0,a=−1,a=1$?